# intellij ctrl+w equivalent shortcut in Netbeans

Tags: intellij-idea, netbeans

In IntelliJ, if the editor cursor is in the middle of a word like this  w|ord and you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, it will highlight the whole word which allows you to highlight the whole word without moving the cursor to the end or the beginning of the word then do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd>.

What's the equivalent in Netbeans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to select/highlight the word at the current cursor position in NetBeans just double-click. You can do the same in Intellij IDEA. Both IDEs will also highlight other occurrences of the selection.

**Ctrl+W** in Intellij IDEA is more powerful than that. It is language aware, and supports incremental selection, so that if you keep clicking **Ctrl+W** it selects larger portions of your source code. Unfortunately I don't know of any equivalent in NetBeans.

Answer (score 0):

In netbeans you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd> which selects next word occurrence. However, you can use it **once**, and you will get the same functionality as in IntelliJ <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd>